# jQuery, $(document) is catching things I do not want it to

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown menu system setup such as this...

This is the scripting section of the HTML page.

```
    $('.ui-dropdown').each(function () {
        $(this).dropdown();
    });
```

Then in the actual HTML...

```
            <li class="ui-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Dropdown Menu</a>
                <div>
                    Test
                </div>
            </li>
```

It works very simply. the `div` is set to `display: none;`. Then there are methods in the jQuery plugin.

```
    // drop the menu down so that it can be seen.
    function drop(e) {
        // show the menu section.
        options.menu.show();
    }

    // lift the menu up, hiding it from view.
    function lift(e) {
        if (!options.menu.is(':visible'))
            return;
        options.menu.hide();
    }
```

Now, this works okay, but I want the menu to vanish when someone clicks anywhere other than the components inside of the `div` or the menu's triggering button. To try and fix that approach, I added this code.

```
$(document).click(lift);
```

This works, a little too well. It is catching (obviously) everything, including clicks to the button, the menu, etc. So I tried to fix it with the following functions.

options is defined as follows.

```
    options.button = $(this);
    options.menu = $(this).find('> div');
    options.links = $(this).find('> a');

    options.button.click(function (e) {
        options.menu.is(':visible') ? lift() : drop();
        e.stopPropogation(); // prevent event bubbling
    });

    options.links.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //prevent event bubbling
    });

    options.menu.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent event bubbling
    });
```

But still no avail. How can I get `$(document).click(lift)` to be ignored when the menu I am wishing to be interacted with is clicked upon?

---

Below is the entire jQuery Plugin, just for reference.

```
jQuery.fn.dropdown = function () {
    var defaults = {
        class: null,
        button: null,
        menu: null
    };
    return this.each(function () {

        // initialize options for each dropdown list, since there
        // very well may be more than just one.
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // specifically assign the option components.
        options.class = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
        options.list = $(this); // keep a constant reference to the root.
        options.button = $(this).find('> a');
        options.menu = $(this).find('> div');

        // bind the lift event to the document click.
        // This will allow the menu to collapse if the user
        // clicks outside of it; but we will stop event bubbling to
        // keep it from being affected by the internal document links.
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);

            // check to see if we have clicked on one of the dropdowns, and if so, dismiss
            // the execution. We only want to lift one if we're not trying to interact with
            // one.
            if ($target.is(options.class) || $target.closest(options.class).length)
                return false;

            lift(e);
        });

        // when the button is clicked, determine the state of the
        // dropdown, and decide whether or not it needs to be lifted
        // or lowered.
        options.button.click(function (e) {
            options.menu.is(':visible') ? lift() : drop();
            e.stopPropogation(); // prevent event bubbling
        });

        // drop the menu down so that it can be seen.
        function drop(e) {
            // show the menu section.
            options.menu.show();
            // style the button that drops the menu, just for aesthetic purposes.
            options.list.addClass("open");
        }

        // lift the menu up, hiding it from view.
        function lift(e) {
            if (!options.menu.is(':visible'))
                return;
            options.menu.hide();


            // style the button that drops the menu, just for aesthetic purposes.
            options.list.removeClass('open');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you have an example page? Your approach should be stopping the `document` receiving the `click`, so something's not quite right here...your approach is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the target on the click first to make sure that they didn't click in the list.

```
jQuery.fn.dropdown = function () {
    var defaults = {
        button: null,
        menu: null,
        links: null,
        identClass: 'my-dropdown'
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass( options.identClass );
        /* ... */
    });

    /* ... */

    // lift the menu up, hiding it from view.
    function lift() {
        if (!options.menu.is(':visible'))
            return;
        options.menu.hide();
    }
    $(document).click(function(){
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ( $target.is('.' + options.identClass) || $target.closest('.' + options.identClass).length ) {
            return;
        }
        lift();
    });
};
```

Comment: I have updated the post to show the entire plugin, if it helps.

Comment: @Stacey I believe the new example I have will work for you.  It checks to see if you clicked on a `.ui-dropdown` element first and then to see if it is a child of a `.ui-dropdown`.

Comment: This does solve the problem of the $(document).click. But using this method, the lift() method does not work if directly invoked by clicking on the menu again.

Comment: What if I wrap the target checking code in (document).click(function(e){ });? Would that cause too many event wirings?

Comment: @Stacey I didn't notice you posted the full source.  I updated my example to work with your situation.

Comment: Hrnm, unfortunately, no, this still isn't doing anything. I don't see where it is calling the lift(e) function. I have tried replacing 'return true' with that call and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah! I was missing the 'e' parameter in the click(function() statement. I believe this solves it. Let me post the updated source.

Comment: Can you explain what the '.closest' is for? I do not understand the use of this function in the statement.

Comment: @Stacey - It checks to see if you clicked on a child of `.ui-dropdown`, like the `a` tags, for instance.

Comment: Also, is there any way to use the options. elements inside the plugin, instead of hard coded css classes? I am trying it that way and that fails. The plugin needs to be independent of the css classes.

Comment: For instance, I have tried if ($target.is(options.button) || $target.closest(options.button).length) - and it simply does not work. it only works if I put in the hard-coded .css values.

Comment: Also, the 'closest' thing isn't doing that. If I click on anything that is a child of the parent element, it still fires the 'lift' function.

Comment: I thought I had it working, but no, this still isn't quite going to function right. The .closest doesn't work - I can put child elements in, and any attempt to interact with them triggers the lift.

Comment: Okay, actually, I think I've figured out the issue. I'll post an update momentarily explaining the confusion.

Comment: Have your plugin add a class.  Reference my example now.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct.I did that in a little bit of a different way. I have updated the plugin code to illustrate my solution. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This works, but unfortunately not in this case. Very poor performance, check out Nick Craver's comments below.

You can use the following selector to select everything but your menu.

$(':not(selector)')

You could try the faster equivalent method .not(selector) on your document selector to select everything on the page except the menu. Haven't tested this yet though.

Comment: Is there any way to cascade this with multiple things? Could you provide an example? I am a little confused as to how you are proposing I use this.

Comment: Please don't do this, it's a very, *very* bad way to solve the problem, binding potentially thousands of event handlers.

Comment: The not selector is not supported by IE

Comment: @Wolfy87 - This is jQuery, it's supported everywhere, but it remains a very bad idea in this case.

Comment: That is a fair comment, didn't think about that. Well, so much for my two cents.

Comment: @Stacey...if by cascade you mean chain?  Then yes.  All functions of the jQuery object return the same list...this is called "chaining". This way you can do cool things like $(".contentWrapper").css("color", "green").show(); and so on.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the entire plugin, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the lift function why not check if the elements id/class **is not** your dropdown, and if so, hide it.

For example:

```
function lift()
{
    if(this.getAttribute('class') != 'ui-dropdown')
    {
        // Hide it
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, but I am a newbie to jQuery. I am unsure of how to go about this. How would I check that?

Comment: I have appended an example, it might need tweeking because it is not tested but still

Answer (score 0):

What I did in this instance is close all the menus and then display the one that was actually clicked.

For example:

```
$('.ui-dropdown').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.ui-dropdown').hide();
   $(this).show();
   return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('ui-dropdown').hide();
);
```

Comment: Wouldnt this provoke a 'flash' on the screen?

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate this into the jQuery plugin code. I have this all wrapped into a simple plugin method named .dropdown();

Comment: @Rickjaah No there is no 'flash' of any kind. Think about clicking on a menu: 1) close all menus, 2) show the selected menu. This is intuitive functionality.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Would it help if I posted the entire plugin?

Comment: @Stacey Just use this code instead of the code you use for options.*.click();

Comment: But if the user decides to click on the same menu again, this does occur. You would be correct if you would use something like $(this).siblings(.ui-dropdown).hide() if all these selectors would have the same parent.

Comment: have updated the post to show the entire plugin, if it helps.